# Android process not terminating even after BroadcastRexceiver execution

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver

Am using Network Change listener (in manifest) in android app, here i can observe  once the app received any broadcast app process continues running even after completion of broadcastreceiver execution. I observed this behavior in debug build while connected to studio, is this is the behavior in the real-time also ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would like the process to not be in the background?

Comment: Yes, in my library am tracking the app usage duration by the app user, but it spoiled everything. Am capturing the start time in Application class and end duration in onStop callback, but in this case i cant take the end timestamp, it the session continues till the user launch the app and push to the background. Even i can't ask the developers to terminate the process after each receiver. Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Well, you should probably only count time in user-relevant components of your app, like Activities, Services and so

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected. By triggering the `BroadcastListener`, Android system started the process of your app. It will then keep this process until it needs to kill it for resources.

This does not mean that any user-relevant components of your app (like `Activities`, `Services` etc.) are running in the background. Just the process, which is a "box" which houses all that :-)

Comment: _"This does not mean that your app is running in the background"_ This is a very confusing way of putting it. It actually is running in the background, just doing nothing.

Comment: Rephrased it to make it less confusing ^^